# Бот на discordpy

Tags: python, discord.py

Пытаюсь написать своего бота для дискорда, с проигрыванием музыки и прочим. Столкнулся с проблемой: функции, передаваемые при выполнении команды, выполняются не единажды, а несколько раз. В частности, такая пробелма с очисткой и плеером.
main.py:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import requests

from discord.ext import commands
import bot
from bot import TOKEN, client

_bot = bot.Bot()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as ' + client.user.name)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    result, success = _bot.CheckCmds(message.content, message)

    if len(result.funcs) > 0:
        for func in result.funcs:
            await func()
    if len(result.text) > 0:
        await message.channel.send(result.text)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

bot.py:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import requests
import random
import time
import os
from copy import copy
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from discord.errors import ClientException, NoMoreItems
from discord.player import FFmpegPCMAudio

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

client = discord.Client()

CMSG, CGUILD, VCL, PREVSRC = None, None, None, ''

class VKLastPostsParser(HTMLParser):
    def reset(self):
        HTMLParser.reset(self)
        self.nnn = 0
        self.anek_i = 0
        self.anek = ['', '', '', '']

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        pass


    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'div' and self.nnn == 3:
            self.nnn = 1
            self.anek_i += 1

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.get_starttag_text() == '<div class="wall_item">' and self.nnn < 2:
            self.nnn += 1
        if self.nnn == 2 and self.get_starttag_text() == '<div class="pi_text">' or self.nnn == 3:
            self.anek[self.anek_i] += str(data) + '\n'
            self.nnn = 3

def GetMemberID(from_string):
    for sym in '<@!>': from_string = from_string.replace(sym, ' ')
    return from_string
def GetMember(uid):
    global client
    return client.guilds[0].get_member(int(uid))
def GetMembersGuilds(uid):
    global client
    l = []
    for g in client.guilds:
        l.append(g.get_member(int(uid)))
    return l
def _GetHighestRole(roles):
    h = 0
    for r in roles:
        if r.position > h:
            h = r.position
    return h
def GetHighestRole(member):
    return _GetHighestRole(member.roles)
def IsHighestRole(num, guild):
    return num == _GetHighestRole(guild.roles)

class Bot:
    kbreasons = [
        '111',
    ]
    games_short = {
        'LOL': 'League of Legends',
        'Over': 'Overwatch',
        'Mine': 'Minecraft',
        'Ter': 'Terraria'
    }
    class Command:
        class RS:
            def __init__(self, text='', funcs=[]):
                self.text = text
                self.funcs = funcs

        prefix = '!'

        def __init__(self, name, mask, command, helpText, restricted_only=[], aliases=[]):
            self.name = name
            self.mask = mask
            self.command = command
            self.helpText = helpText
            self.restricted_only = restricted_only
            self.aliases = aliases

        def Run(self, rargs):
            global CMSG
            troles = [str(r) for r in CMSG.author.roles]
            f = False
            for r in self.restricted_only:
                if r in troles:
                    f = True
                    break
            if len(self.restricted_only) > 0 and not f:
                return Bot.Command.RS(text=' еще не вырос. Скажешь, как подрастет.')

            if rargs.startswith('/?'):
                return Bot.Command.RS(text=self.helpText)
            if self.mask == '':
                return self.command({})

            strs = []
            T = rargs
            while T.find('"') != -1:
                T = T[T.find('"') + 1:]
                zz = T[:T.find('"')]
                strs.append(zz)
                rargs = rargs.replace('"' + zz +'"', '%%cc')
                T = T[T.find('"') + 1:] if len(T) > T.find('"') + 1 else ''

            rargs = rargs.split(' ')
            mask = self.mask.split(' ')

            res = {}

            total = 0
            rq = 0
            for par in mask:
                required = par.find('(') != -1
                for c in '([])':
                    par = par.replace(c, '')
                par = par.split(':')

                name = par[0]
                typ = par[1] if len(par) > 1 else ''
                defVal = par[2] if len(par) > 2 else ''

                if required: rq += 1

                if len(rargs) > total:
                    rarg = rargs[total]

                    if defVal != '':
                        if rarg == defVal:
                            res[name] = True
                        else:
                            res[name] = False
                    else:
                        try:
                            if rarg == '%%cc' and len(strs) > 0:
                                rarg = strs[0]
                                strs.pop(0)
                            if typ == 'INT':
                                res[name] = int(rarg)
                            elif typ == 'FLOAT':
                                res[name] = float(rarg)
                            else:
                                if name.find('member') >= 0:
                                    tr = GetHighestRole(GetMember(GetMemberID(str(rarg))))
                                    mr = GetHighestRole(CMSG.author)
                                    if tr >= mr and not IsHighestRole(mr, CMSG.author.guild):
                                        return Bot.Command.RS(text=' еще не вырос. Скажешь, как подрастет.')

                                res[name] = str(rarg)
                        except:
                            res[name] = 0
                    total += 1
                else:
                    res[name] = False

            if total < rq:
                raise Exception("Слишком мало аргументов")

            return self.command(res)

        @staticmethod
        def RemoveThisMessage(args):
            global CMSG
            res = Bot.Command.RS()
            res.text = 'Deleted, ' + args['suqa'] + '!'
            res.funcs = [lambda: CMSG.channel.delete_messages([CMSG])]
            return res

        @staticmethod
        def Kick(args):
            res = Bot.Command.RS()

            reason = Bot.kbreasons[args['reason']]
            print(type(args['member']).__name__, type(args['91']).__name__, type(reason).__name__)

            res.text = args['member'] + ' кикнут' + (' 99' if args['91'] else '') + ' (' + reason + ')!'

            uid = GetMemberID(args['member'])

            members = GetMembersGuilds(uid)
            if not args['91'] and len(members) > 0:
                members = [members[0]]
            #print(type(member).__name__, member)

            res.funcs = []
            for member in members:
                res.funcs.append(lambda: member.kick(reason=reason))

            return res

        @staticmethod
        def Ban(args):
            res = Bot.Command.RS()

            reason = Bot.kbreasons[args['reason']]

            res.text = args['member'] + ' забанен' + (' 99' if args['91'] else '') + ' (' + reason + ')' + '!'

            uid = GetMemberID(args['member'])

            members = GetMembersGuilds(uid)
            if not args['91'] and len(members) > 0:
                members = [members[0]]
            #print(type(member).__name__, member)

            res.funcs = []
            for member in members:
                res.funcs.append(lambda: member.ban(delete_message_days=(7 if args['91'] else 0), reason=reason))

            return res

        @staticmethod
        def Anek(args):
            href = 'https://vk.com/jumoreski'
            h = requests.get(href).text
            p = VKLastPostsParser()
            p.feed(h)
            p.close()
            r = random.randint(0, 2)
            return Bot.Command.RS(text = 'Анекдот из ' + href + ' (' + str(r) + '):\n' + p.anek[r])

        @staticmethod
        def Purge(args):
            global CMSG
            res = Bot.Command.RS()
            res.funcs.append(lambda: CMSG.channel.purge(limit=10))
            return res

        @staticmethod
        def WhoIsIn(args):
            global CMSG, client

            res = Bot.Command.RS()
            game = ''
            try: game = Bot.games_short[args['game']]
            except: game = args['game']

            r2 = ''
            total = 0
            for guild in client.guilds:
                for member in guild.members:
                    if member == None: continue
                    act = member.activity
                    actname = act.name if act != None else 'None'
                    if actname.lower() == game.lower():
                        r2 += member.display_name + '\n'
                        total += 1

            res.text = 'В ' + game + ' сейчас играют (' + str(total) + '):\n' + (r2 if total > 0 else ':(')

            return res

        @staticmethod
        async def StopVoice():
            global VCL, PREVSRC
            try:
                await VCL.disconnect()
            except: pass
            finally: PREVSRC = '__SKIP__'
        @staticmethod
        async def StartVoice(nsrc):
            global CMSG, VCL

            try:
                c =  CMSG.author.voice.channel
                VCL = await c.connect()
            except: pass

            while VCL == None:
                time.sleep(0.5)
            #try:
            global PREVSRC#os.path.exists(nsrc)
            if PREVSRC != '__SKIP__' and nsrc != PREVSRC:
                if VCL.is_playing():
                    VCL.source = FFmpegPCMAudio(nsrc, executable='D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe')
                    PREVSRC = nsrc
                    #VCL.stop()
                else:
                    print(nsrc, PREVSRC, VCL.is_playing())
                    VCL.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(nsrc, executable='D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe'))
            print('zaloop started')
            #except: pass

        @staticmethod
        def Play(args):
            global VCL, PREVSRC
            res = Bot.Command.RS()

            if PREVSRC == '__SKIP__': PREVSRC = ''

            res.funcs.append(lambda: Bot.Command.StartVoice(args['src']))

            res.text = 'Сейчас играет: ' + args['src']
            return res

        @staticmethod
        def StopPlaying(args):
            global PREVSRC, VCL
            res = Bot.Command.RS()
            res.funcs = [Bot.Command.StopVoice]

            res.text = 'Плеер остановлен.'

            return res
        @staticmethod
        def SkipPlaying(args):
            if VCL != None:
                PREVSRC = '__SKIP__'
                VCL.stop()
            return Bot.Command.RS(text='Композиция пропущена.')

        @staticmethod
        def Howl(args):
            return Bot.Command.RS(funcs=[lambda: Bot.Command.StartVoice('Howl.mp3')], text='*Вой вам в голосовой*')
        @staticmethod
        def Whine(args):
            return Bot.Command.RS(funcs=[lambda: Bot.Command.StartVoice('Whine.mp3')], text='*Скулеж*')


    def Help(self, args):
        res = Bot.Command.RS()
        res.text = 'Помощь:\n'
        for c in self.commands:
            res.text += c.name + str(c.aliases) + ' ' + c.mask + ': ' + c.helpText + '\n'
            res.text += '\n'
        return res


    commands = []

    def CheckCmds(self, com, msg):
        global CMSG
        CMSG = msg
        CGUILD = msg.channel.guild

        result = Bot.Command.RS()
        success = False

        #try:
        for cmd in self.commands:
            tr = copy(cmd.aliases)
            tr.append(cmd.name)
            for t in tr:
                if com.lower().startswith(Bot.Command.prefix + t):
                    result = cmd.Run(com[len(Bot.Command.prefix + t) + 1:])
                    success = True
        #except Exception as e:
            #result.text = str(e)
            #print(e)
        #finally:
        if result is str:
            result = Bot.Command.RS()
        return result, success

    def __init__(self):
        self.commands.append(Bot.Command('removethis', '(suqa:)', Bot.Command.RemoveThisMessage, ''))

        h = ' (@юзер) (причина_число) [99]\nЕсли написать 99, то действие выполнится на всех серверах с ботом.\nПричины:\n'
        for i in range(len(Bot.kbreasons)):
            h += str(i) + ' - ' + Bot.kbreasons[i] + '\n'

        self.commands.append(Bot.Command('забань', '(member:) (reason:INT) [91::99]', Bot.Command.Ban, 'забань' + h))
        self.commands.append(Bot.Command('кикни', '(member:) (reason:INT) [91::99]', Bot.Command.Kick, 'кикни' + h))
        self.commands.append(Bot.Command('чистка', '', Bot.Command.Purge, 'Чистит канал', aliases = ['смыв', 'смой', 'убери это 99', 'спуск']))

        self.commands.append(Bot.Command('повой', '', Bot.Command.Howl, 'Вытье вам в ухо', aliases=['повыть', 'вой']))
        self.commands.append(Bot.Command('поскули', '', Bot.Command.Whine, 'Скулеж вам в ухо', aliases=['поскулить', 'скули']))
        self.commands.append(Bot.Command('анекдот', '', Bot.Command.Anek, 'Анеки', aliases = ['анек', 'лол', 'lol']))
        self.commands.append(Bot.Command('play', '(src:)', Bot.Command.Play, 'Проигрывает музыку с компа одмена, или из url (должна быть ссылка на файл!)', aliases = ['!', 'p']))
        self.commands.append(Bot.Command('stop', '(src:)', Bot.Command.StopPlaying, 'Остановить проигрыватель', aliases = ['/', 's']))
        self.commands.append(Bot.Command('skip', '(src:)', Bot.Command.SkipPlaying, 'Пропустить композицию', aliases = ['-', 's']))

        h = 'кто в ("name of game"). Список участников, играющих в game.\nСписок кратких названий:\n'
        for k in Bot.games_short:
            h += k + ' = ' + Bot.games_short[k] + '\n'
        self.commands.append(Bot.Command('кто в', '(game:)', Bot.Command.WhoIsIn, h))

        self.commands.append(Bot.Command('памаги', '', self.Help, '', aliases = ['?', 'help', 'h', 'помогите', 'памагити']))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилась эта проблема такими правками:

```py
@staticmethod
def Purge(args):
    global CMSG
    return Bot.Command.RS(funcs=[lambda: CMSG.channel.purge(limit=10)], text='http://img.labnol.org/di/windows_logo.png')

@staticmethod
async def StopVoice():
    global VCL
    try: await VCL.disconnect()
    except: pass
@staticmethod
async def StartVoice(nsrc):
    global CMSG, VCL

    try:
        c =  CMSG.author.voice.channel
        VCL = await c.connect()
    except: pass

    while VCL == None:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    if VCL.is_playing():
        VCL.source = FFmpegPCMAudio(nsrc, executable='D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe')
    else:
        VCL.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(nsrc, executable='D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe'))

@staticmethod
def Play(args):
    return Bot.Command.RS(text='Сейчас играет: ' + args['src'], funcs=[lambda: Bot.Command.StartVoice(args['src'])])

@staticmethod
def StopPlaying(args):
    global VCL
    res = Bot.Command.RS()
    res.funcs = [Bot.Command.StopVoice]

    res.text = 'Плеер остановлен.'

    return res
@staticmethod
def SkipPlaying(args):
    if VCL != None:
        VCL.stop()
    return Bot.Command.RS(text='Композиция пропущена.')
```

Буду крайне презнателен, если кто-то разъяснит, почему оно работало не так.